# Most known teachers of specific branch of Science

Tags: mathematics, chemistry, biology, book-recommendation

After acquainting myself with the works of Richard Feynman in Physics: *" The Feynman Lectures on Physics"* and partially with the works of Donald Knuth in Programming: *"The Art of Computer Programming"*, both amazingly interesting, inspiring and attempting a holistic approach in the introduction and explanation of the respective field, I am wondering are there other authors with similar style in other fields of Science, e.g Mathematics, Chemistry, Biology and what are the titles of their works.

---

Answer (score 2):

The whole series *"A course on Theoretical Physics."* (in 10 volumes) by L. Landau and E. Lifshitz partially fits the bill, although the style is terse and entirely hypnotic. The lectures are certainly aspirational and certainly holistic, but well beyond elementary level.

Answer (score 1):

John Maynard Smith in Evolutionary Biology.

(Richard Dawkins and Stephen Jay Gould are/were probably the most famous writers on Evolutionary Biology, but both's famous writings were for popular audiences, and nontechnical.)